# How to pass parameter in People Picker selecteditem React Control

Tags: reactjs, spfx

How to pass **parameter** in people picker react **selecteditem** function--this works for me
```
<PeoplePicker
context={this.props.context}
//titleText="Name"
personSelectionLimit={1}
showtooltip={true}
// isRequired={true}
//    disabled={(this.state.FormName!="View") ? false : true}
placeholder="Enter Regional DCSO Lead Email ID"
selectedItems={this._getPeoplePickerItems.bind(this,"1")}
showHiddenInUI={false}
//       defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.RegionalDCSOLead}
ensureUser={true}
principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
resolveDelay={1000} />

```
private _getPeoplePickerItems(itemid,items: any[]) {  
  let getSelectedUsers = [];  
  for (let item in items) {  
    getSelectedUsers.push(items[item].loginName.replace("i:0#.f|membership|","")
  );  
  }  
  //this.setState({ RegionalEmail: getSelectedUsers }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 How to pass parameter in people picker react selecteditem function--this works for me
 
 <PeoplePicker  
  context={this.props.context}  
   //titleText="Name"  
   personSelectionLimit={1}  
  showtooltip={true}  
  // isRequired={true}  
  //    disabled={(this.state.FormName!="View") ? false : true}  
  placeholder="Enter Regional DCSO Lead Email ID"
  selectedItems={this._getPeoplePickerItems.bind(this,"1")} 
  showHiddenInUI={false}  
  //       defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.RegionalDCSOLead}
  ensureUser={true}  
  principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}  
  resolveDelay={1000} />

private _getPeoplePickerItems(itemid,items: any[]) {  
  let getSelectedUsers = [];  
  for (let item in items) {  
    getSelectedUsers.push(items[item].loginName.replace("i:0#.f|membership|","")
  );  
  }  
  //this.setState({ RegionalEmail: getSelectedUsers }); 
};
```